Error trying to run a python script from a Google Cloud DAG
I have created a DAG in a bucket in Google Cloud, and want to run a python script which I have saved in the scripts folder of the bucket. However, I am either faced with a DAG Import error or a folder/file not found error.
In my DAG I have the following task defined:
task2 = BashOperator(
 task_id='execute_python_code',
 bash_command=f'python /europe-west8-cellxpert-blablabla-bucket/dags/scripts/cellxpert_transactions_script.py ',
 dag=dag,
)

The python script is saved in the scripts folder, and no matter what address I add after f'python, I get the following error:
python: can't open file '/europe-west8-cellxpert-blablabla-bucket/dags/scripts/cellxpert_transactions_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I've also tried using an environment variable like this:
DAGS_FOLDER = os.environ["DAGS_FOLDER"]
bash_command=f'python {DAGS_FOLDER}/scripts/cellxpert_transactions_script.py',

(and also with "AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER") but then I get a DAG Import error
DAGS_FOLDER = os.environ["DAGS_FOLDER"]
                  ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 679, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'DAGS_FOLDER'

I'm pulling my hair out, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Hello. What is the reason to execute python indirectly, but not using python operator?

I am making an API call to pull an XML file which I'm then pushing to BigQuery. When I checked how to do it, using DAG and a python file was what I found. Do you think it could work with python operator?

If the XML file is small then you should be fine using python operator. If this processes might be considered as memory intensive then you need to use 3rd-party engine like some containers service and only orchestrate it using airflow

I intend to schedule it daily so it shouldn't be a large file. Do you have any suggestion for a python operator tutorial?

Based on the comment tread, please, just take a look at basics - https://academy.astronomer.io/path/airflow-101
And about working with Python - https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/airflow-decorators
